# Eliminate render-blocking resources

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am a newbie with progressive web apps. I want to increase the performance of my PWA but stuck at one point.

This is the error

[image]

Please help me to resolve this!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [page](https://csabapalfi.github.io/eliminate-render-blocking/) on how to eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS.

> Critical-path styles are the styles that are required to render correctly everything that's **above the fold**.
>
> You should inline these styles to avoid additional HTTP requests blocking initial rendering. You'll find that there's a [collection of tools to help with this](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical-path-css-tools).
>
> ```
> <head>
>   ...
>   <style>critical CSS rules here</style>
>   ...
> </head>
> ```

Some additional tips:

> - You should consider figuring out what above-the-fold means for your users based on web analytics.
> - Also make sure you don't use `@import` statements in critical CSS as that'll also trigger additional HTTP requests.
> - Be sure not to inline too much CSS as that'll also slow down your initial render.
> - Read some more explanation/tips from [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) and [Varvy](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html).